# Apache camel saml authentication

Tags: apache, apache-camel, cxf, single-sign-on, saml

Anyone implemented SAML SSO authentication using Apache camel? I need sample authentication code for same in Apache camel.I checked in that camel site but didn't find any useful information

Answer (score 1):

Read the section on [Spring Security integration](http://camel.apache.org/camel-security.html), you need to implement the AuthorizationPolicy using camel-spring-security module. The [Spring Security SAML](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml) project on GitHub have a sample application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.The documentation describes implementation of saml authentication.But my use case is different.
I have my content behind the saml authentication.I have to crawl my content after successful authentication against saml sso using Apache camel.